# How is possible to execute a piece of code when an object is created in PHP-DI?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, constructor, callback, php-di

I set up my dependencies with `\DI\Container` like this:

```
$this->container = new \DI\Container();
$this->container->set('AdyenClient', \DI\create('\Adyen\Client'));
$this->container->set('AdyenCheckout', \DI\create('\Adyen\Service\Checkout')->constructor($this->container->get('AdyenClient')));
```

The `\Adyen\Client` cannot be configured in construction, so I need to execute a `configClient()` function, not associated in any way with the created object, after it's been created for the first time.

Is it possible to 'trigger' that method or any other piece of code the first time the object is being created by `$this->container->get('AdyenClient')`, even if it is needed to alter the way the dependencies are set up?

Nothing in the official documentation has a similar scenario as far as I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With DI\create()

You may use [CreateDefinitionHelper::method](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/blob/master/src/Definition/Helper/CreateDefinitionHelper.php#L107-L130) to define method call when the object is created. Like this:

```php
$this->container = new \DI\Container();
$this->container->set('AdyenClient',
  \DI\create('\Adyen\Client')->method('configClient', $param1, $param2));
$this->container->set('AdyenCheckout',
  \DI\create('\Adyen\Service\Checkout')->constructor($this->container->get('AdyenClient')));
```

PHP-DI will call AdyenClient::configClient with $param1 and $param2 after first created.

### With DI\factory()

Alternatively, you may use the `DI\factory` function (which creates [FactoryDefinitionHelper](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/blob/master/src/Definition/Helper/FactoryDefinitionHelper.php) from a callback):

```php
$this->container = new \DI\Container();
$this->container->set('AdyenClient',
  \DI\factory(function (Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container) {
    $adyenClient = $container->get('\Adyen\Client');
    configClient($adyenClient);
    return $adyenClient;
  });
$this->container->set('AdyenCheckout',
  \DI\create('\Adyen\Service\Checkout')->constructor($this->container->get('AdyenClient')));
```

This should be a more flexible way to define any lazy-loaded thing in the container.

Comment: Hi @Koala Yeung. Thanks for the answer, but the method ```configClient``` doesn't exist in the ```AdyenClient``` class and neither I can extend it with it as it's not written by me. 

I need to be able to call any other piece of code not directly associated with the created object.

Comment: Finally I did it by chaining all configuration methods available in the ```AdyenClient``` object.

Comment: @KristosAthanasiadis: Added another approach to the answer. It should be more flexible.

Comment: Even though, I did it by following your first example, which produces some ugly [hard to read] code --because, there are several config methods in that specific class, the second way is truly what I needed from the beginning.

In general the \DI\Factory approach is the preferred method, when --as in my case, the configuration of the created object is not limited to one method.

Thanks for your effort nevertheless!